# Wrapping paragraphs in p tags

Tags: html

I have a HTML Document that has correct paragraph formatting for most of the text But there are some paragraphs that don't contain p tags and as such are not displaying correctly.

Is there way to inclose paragraphs with `<p> </p>` tags using a text editor with regular expressions? I tried using HTML tidy, but I cant get it to recognize separate paragraphs or it reformats it in the wrong way, I dont know what is going on...

I need each paragraph that doesnt already contain html tags to have the paragraphs wrapped:

```
Template Design Creation for the layout for the content that will exist on each page.

Custom Programing to make certain features work with the design.

Photos of the Location For the Website Design Elements.
```

Like this

```
<p>Template Design Creation for the layout for the content that will exist on each page.</p>

<p>Custom Programing to make certain features work with the design.</p>

<p>Photos of the Location For the Website Design Elements.</p>'
```

Comment: If this is a one time thing, wouldn't is be easier to just do it manually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using regular expressions:

```
/($|\n|^)/$1<\/p>\n<p>/g
```

Is the easiest, but it requires cleaning up an extra close tag at the start of the document and an extra open tag at the end. It is possible to get it perfect but I don't find it's worth the trouble.

Comment: I agree with @Adrian, regardless of what you try and put in place you will still have to go through the document and sort the tags out. If you are using DW just switch to design view and do it from there. It will take time, but will be quicker than traversing raw HTML.

Comment: Thank you, sorry for the late closing of this, i got side tracked. I got it to work using the search and replace you recommended.

Answer (score 0):

I'd agree with the guy above, just add them in manually. If the content is coming from a web page on your server just deploy a WYSIWYG editor (loads of them around) and they should cater for that function.

Comment: its a big document. I converted a pdf book to html so I can convert that to and .epub file. Since its a mixed HTML and TXT document Im having some trouble finding the right method for this can I tried to use a wysiwyg editor but it doesnt reformat the paragraphs that dont have tags. does anyone have one they know that would work for this?